# Number of ways to forming a committee of 2 persons from 4 couples such that a married couple does not serve on committee

Tags: combinatorics

One of answering this question is considering in how many ways we can select 2 couples out of 4 couples ($^4C_2$) and then multiplying by it with number of ways one person can be chosen from each of the two selected couples ($2^2$). So, the answer is $^4C_2 \times 2^2 = 24$.

The second way of solving this problem is to find the total number of ways a committee of 2 can be formed from 8 persons ($^8C_2$) and then subtracting from it the number of ways a couple serves in the committee which is $^4C_1$. So, the answer is $^8C_2 - ^4C_1 = 24$.

Is this the correct way of solving this problem?

Comment: Both methods are valid/accurate.